# High number of factor level regression in R

Tags: r

I am running into troubles with some regressions in R.

I need to do run a relatively simple regression model.

I have few samples (n) and 1 factor with 6000 factor levels. For each of these n*6000 'cells' I have 1 value, which is count data. I want to do a regression to get rid of sample specific and factor specific effects and in a second step i want to compare the distribution of residuals of each sample. Why regression? Well, I want to test different conversion (log conversion+linear regression; GLM models etc)

The method is validated and does work. However, I run into troubles since scaling up from let's say 500 factors to 6000. I keep getting 'cannot run with less than 8GB memory errors'. I have tried LME4 en MatrixModels package, however I keep running into troubles.

Anyone else having a trick to process high dimensional factors (and thus big matrices) ?

thx

Comment: Have you tried `biglm`?

Comment: Search this forum for `big memory` where you will find all sorts of ideas.

Comment: can you show a small example?  I know the question is "how do I scale this up to a big data set", but a more concrete example would help me figure out what you're doing and e.g. whether a sparse-X-matrix approach would help ...